# Sideways Table not created

Tags: floats

```
 \begin{sidewaystable}[tbp]
  \centering
   \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
    \caption{Table 3(a). Market Leverage Linear Regressions  }
        \hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
   % \toprule
        \hline%
    \multirow{Dependent variable} & \multirow{Market } & \multirow{Leverage} & \multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt} & \multirow{+} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} & \multirow{of Equity)} \\
        \hline%
  %  \midrule
          &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    Estimation Method & Pooled OLS without time Dummies  & Pooled OLS with time Dummies & OLS Firm Clustered Standard Errors & OLS Time Clustered & \multicolumn{2}{r}{Fama- Macbeth} & Newey West \\
    \multirow{Intercept} & 0.26  & 0.22  & 0.26  & 0.26  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{0.257} & 0.257 \\
          & (\textless.0001) &  (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & -0.004 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-0.003} & (\textless.0001) \\
    \multirow{\pie(dynamics)} & 0.55  & 0.68  & 0.55  & 0.55  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{0.643} & 0.643 \\
          & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & \multicolumn{2}{r}{(\textless.0001)} & (\textless.0001) \\
          &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    \multirow{/beta_1 (Operating Profit Margin )  } & -1.96E-03 & -1.55E-03 & -1.96E-03 & -1.96E-03 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-0.001} & -0.001 \\
          & -0.0004 & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & -0.002 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-0.019} & -0.001 \\
    \multirow{/beta_2 (Market to Book Ratio)} & -0.01 & -0.01 & -0.01 & -0.01 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-0.033} & -0.033 \\
          & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & (-0.002) & (-0.018) & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-0.04} & (-0.067) \\
    \multirow{/beta_3 (Current Assets Change) } & 5.19E-05 & 5.11E-05 & 5.19E-05 & 5.19E-05 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{3.59E-05} & 3.59E-05 \\
          & (-0.0259) & (-0.01) & (-0.004) & (-0.057) & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-0.225} & -0.015 \\
    \multirow{/beta_4 (Average Borrowing Cost)} & -2.04E-03 & -3.29E-03 & -2.04E-03 & -2.04E-03 & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-0.005} & -0.005 \\
          & (-0.2984) & (-0.04) & (-0.299) & (-0.334) & \multicolumn{2}{r}{-0.02} & (0.005 \\
    \multirow{Y\_2006} & \multirow{} & -0.183 & \multirow{} & \multirow{} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{}} & \multirow{} \\
          &       & (\textless.0001) &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    \multirow{Y\_2008} & \multirow{} & -0.093 & \multirow{} & \multirow{} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{}} & \multirow{} \\
          &       & -0.001 &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    \multirow{Y\_2009} & \multirow{} & 0.244 & \multirow{} & \multirow{} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{}} & \multirow{} \\
          &       & (\textless.0001) &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    \multirow{Y\_2010} & \multirow{} & -0.146 & \multirow{} & \multirow{} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{}} & \multirow{} \\
          &       & (\textless.0001) &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    \multirow{NT (Total Observation)} & \multirow{320} & \multirow{320} & \multirow{320} & \multirow{320} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{320}} & \multirow{320} \\
          &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    N (Firms) & 40    & 40    & 40    & 40    & \multicolumn{2}{r}{40} & 40 \\
    T = NT/N & 8     & 8     & 8     & 8     & \multicolumn{2}{r}{8} & 8 \\
    SSE   & 12.23 & 7.9   & -     & -     & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{}} & \multirow{} \\
    MSE   & 0.04  & 0     & 0.2   & 0.2   & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    R-Square & 0.45  & 0.6   & 0.5   & 0.45  & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
          &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    Godfrey test for Auto Correlation &       &       & \multirow{} & \multirow{} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{}} & \multirow{} \\
          &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    AR (1) & 38.6  & 0.75  &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
          & (\textless.0001) & -0.39 &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    AR (2) & 46.5  &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
          & (\textless.0001) &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    AR (3) & 60.9  &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
          & (\textless.0001) &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
          &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{r}{} &  \\
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{( ) Indicates significance P values} & \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{}} \\
        \hline%
   % \bottomrule
        \hspace*{-1cm}\end{tabular}%

\end{sidewaystable}%
```

The error it gives

```
l.258 \caption
{Table 3(a). Market Leverage Linear Regressions }
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\let 
l.258 \caption
{Table 3(a). Market Leverage Linear Regressions }
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\def 
l.258 \caption
{Table 3(a). Market Leverage Linear Regressions }
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\def 
l.258 \caption
{Table 3(a). Market Leverage Linear Regressions }
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)


! LaTeX Error: \begin{lrbox} on input line 225 ended by \end{minipage}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.258 \caption
{Table 3(a). Market Leverage Linear Regressions }
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.

Adding sideways figure on right hand page

! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.258 \caption
{Table 3(a). Market Leverage Linear Regressions }
You've lost some text. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.258 \caption
{Table 3(a). Market Leverage Linear Regressions }
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Argument of \@xmultirow has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.262 \multirow{Dependent variable} &
\multirow{Market } & \multirow{Lev...
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
D
l.262 \multirow{Dependent variable} &
\multirow{Market } & \multirow{Lev...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 \multirow{Dependent variable} &
\multirow{Market } & \multirow{Lev...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 \multirow{Dependent variable} &
\multirow{Market } & \multirow{Lev...
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)


Overfull \vbox (12.0pt too high) detected at line 262
[]

! Argument of \@xmultirow has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.262 ...ependent variable} & \multirow{Market } &
\multirow{Leverage} & \mu...
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
M
l.262 ...ependent variable} & \multirow{Market } &
\multirow{Leverage} & \mu...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...ependent variable} & \multirow{Market } &
\multirow{Leverage} & \mu...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...ependent variable} & \multirow{Market } &
\multirow{Leverage} & \mu...
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)


Overfull \vbox (12.0pt too high) detected at line 262
[]

! Argument of \@xmultirow has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.262 ...multirow{Market } & \multirow{Leverage} &
\multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt}...
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
L
l.262 ...multirow{Market } & \multirow{Leverage} &
\multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt}...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...multirow{Market } & \multirow{Leverage} &
\multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt}...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...multirow{Market } & \multirow{Leverage} &
\multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt}...
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)


Overfull \vbox (12.0pt too high) detected at line 262
[]

! Argument of \@xmultirow has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.262 ...w{Leverage} & \multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt} &
\multirow{+} & \multicolu...
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
(
l.262 ...w{Leverage} & \multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt} &
\multirow{+} & \multicolu...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...w{Leverage} & \multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt} &
\multirow{+} & \multicolu...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...w{Leverage} & \multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt} &
\multirow{+} & \multicolu...
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)


Overfull \vbox (12.0pt too high) detected at line 262
[]

! Argument of \@xmultirow has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.262 ...multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt} & \multirow{+} &
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\multi...
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

! Dimension too large.
\@xmultirow ...mpdima \@tempcnta \dp \@arstrutbox 
\ifnum \@tempcnta <0\@temp...
l.262 ...multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt} & \multirow{+} &
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\multi...
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt} & \multirow{+} &
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\multi...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...multirow{ (= Debt/(Debt} & \multirow{+} &
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\multi...
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Argument of \@xmultirow has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.262 ...lticolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }}
& \multirow{of Equity)} \\
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
M
l.262 ...lticolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }}
& \multirow{of Equity)} \\
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...lticolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }}
& \multirow{of Equity)} \\
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\unskip 
l.262 ...lticolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }}
& \multirow{of Equity)} \\
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)


Overfull \vbox (12.0pt too high) detected at line 262
[]

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
\cr 
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
\cr 
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
\cr 
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
\cr 
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
\cr 
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
}
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I've put in what seems to be necessary to fix
the current column of the current alignment.
Try to go on, since this might almost work.

! Missing \cr inserted.
<inserted text> 
\cr 
l.262 ...icolumn{2}{r}{\multirow{Market Value }} &
\multirow{of Equity)} \\
I'm guessing that you meant to end an alignment here.
```

Comment: You have `\multirow{}` all over. Remove them adnd use `\multirow{2}{*}{320}` for example. :)  BTW what is `\pie`? and `\beta_1` should be enclosed by `$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6):

Your table has several problems. Mentioning some of them, in no particular order:

- There are 50 [!] `\multirow` directives in your code, but (a) the syntax of these directives isn't correct and (b) it's not clear *what* they're supposed to achieve. In the code below I've eliminated all of them.
- The table's header is a mess, I hate to have to tell you. You should probably spend some time on re-organizing it.
- Do encase things such as `\beta_1`, `\beta_2`, ... in `$...$` symbols; doing so will invoke inline math mode.
- You have so much material in each column that, should you choose the simple `r` alignment specifier, there's no way the table is going to fit on a page (unless it's the size of a posterboard...) I suggest you load the `tabularx` package and use modified forms of the `X` column type to force automatic line breaks.

  Even with that change, I still found it necessary to reduce the font size by 10% in order to make the entire table fit on a page. Ask yourself if it's possible to break up the table into two parts. Your readers, at any rate, will probably be grateful if you do so.
- Still speaking of columns, the cells in columns 6 and 7 (out of 8) are currently all combined using a `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}` statement. Given that there's no independent existence of these two columns, I propose eliminating all `\multicolumn` wrappers (and reducing the column count in the setup of the tabular/tabularx environment by 1.
- To avoid creating empty rows needlessly, it turns out to be necessary to split the contents of the first column by hand across two rows. I suggest you indent the contents of the continuation row by, say, `\quad` to highlight to your readers that the material constitutes a continuation from the preceding row.
- To force a blank row, it suffices to write `\\`. No need to write something like `& & & & & & & \\`. (Actually, in the code below, I've eliminated all blank lines in order to give the table a chance to fit in the textblock.)
- I would place material such as `( ) Indicates significance of p-values` below the table since, syntactically speaking, it's part of the legend to the table rather than a part of the tabular material itself.
- What is the macro `\pie` supposed to do? In the example below, I'm rendering it as the string "pie"...

Here, then, is my attempt to typeset your table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating,caption,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\def\pie{pie} %% what is \pie?
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\small
\caption{Table 3(a). Market Leverage Linear Regressions}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}L *{6}{R}@{}}
\toprule
Dependent variable& Market & Leverage&  (= Debt/(Debt& +& Market Value  & of Equity) \\[1ex]
Estimation Method & Pooled OLS without time Dummies  & Pooled OLS with time Dummies & OLS Firm Clustered Standard Errors & OLS Time Clustered & Fama-Macbeth& Newey West \\
\midrule
Intercept& 0.26  & 0.22  & 0.26  & 0.26  & 0.257& 0.257 \\
& (\textless.0001) &  (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & -0.004 & -0.003& (\textless.0001) \\
\pie(dynamics)& 0.55  & 0.68  & 0.55  & 0.55  & 0.643& 0.643 \\
 & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001)& (\textless.0001) \\
$\beta_1$ (Operating  & -1.96E-03 & -1.55E-03 & -1.96E-03 & -1.96E-03 & -0.001& -0.001 \\
\quad Profit Margin) & -0.0004 & (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & -0.002 & -0.019& -0.001 \\
$\beta_2$ (Market to & -0.01 & -0.01 & -0.01 & -0.01 & -0.033& -0.033 \\
\quad Book Ratio)& (\textless.0001) & (\textless.0001) & (-0.002) & (-0.018) & -0.04& (-0.067) \\
$\beta_3$ (Current Assets  & 5.19E-05 & 5.11E-05 & 5.19E-05 & 5.19E-05 & 3.59E-05& 3.59E-05 \\
\quad Change)& (-0.0259) & (-0.01) & (-0.004) & (-0.057) & -0.225& -0.015 \\
$\beta_4$ (Average & -2.04E-03 & -3.29E-03 & -2.04E-03 & -2.04E-03 & -0.005& -0.005 \\
\quad Borrowing Cost)& (-0.2984) & (-0.04) & (-0.299) & (-0.334) & -0.02& (0.005 \\
Y\_2006& & -0.183 \\
 & & (\textless.0001) \\
Y\_2008& & -0.093  \\
& & -0.001  \\
Y\_2009& & 0.244 \\
& & (\textless.0001) \\
Y\_2010& & -0.146 \\
& & (\textless.0001)\\[1ex]
$NT$ (Total Obs.)& 320& 320& 320& 320& 320& 320 \\
$N$ (Firms) & 40    & 40    & 40    & 40    & 40& 40 \\
$T = NT/N$ & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8& 8 \\
SSE   & 12.23 & 7.9   & - & -  \\
MSE   & 0.04  & 0 & 0.2   & 0.2  \\
R-Squared & 0.45  & 0.6   & 0.5   & 0.45  \\
Godfrey test for autocorrelation \\
AR (1) & 38.6  & 0.75\\
& (\textless.0001) & -0.39 & \\
AR (2) & 46.5  & \\
& (\textless.0001) \\
AR (3) & 60.9 \\
& (\textless.0001) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
( ) indicates significance of p-values
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```